# SQL - Grouping by one field and summing another field?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, aggregate

I have a database that contains data about page views for items on my site. Each row has a Date, ItemId (guid string), and Views (int). There are many rows with the same ItemId across different dates. I want to aggregate all of these into one row with the sum of the Views. For example:

```
Date                   |ItemId                               |Views
2017-12-18 20:18:00    |6B3B4A9E-B64B-4BAF-9ABA-42F486CC70AB |1
2017-12-17 20:18:00    |6B3B4A9E-B64B-4BAF-9ABA-42F486CC70AB |3
2017-12-12 20:18:00    |6B3B4A9E-B64B-4BAF-9ABA-42F486CC70AB |5
2017-12-07 20:18:00    |6B3B4A9E-B64B-4BAF-9ABA-42F486CC70AB |1
```

I'd like to get the following:

```
ItemId                               | Views
6B3B4A9E-B64B-4BAF-9ABA-42F486CC70AB | 10
```

Additionally, I need to be able to filter by date, like `WHERE [Date] between '12/15/2017' and GetDate()`

The Where clause is easy enough, but how do I do the grouping/summing? Keep in mind that I'm not summing just one ItemId, I want to group all rows where the ItemId is the same so that I can get the sum of the views for every item.

Comment: Select ItemId, SUM(Views) from table where Date > '2017-12-15' group by ItemId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    ItemId,
    SUM(Views) AS Views
FROM yourTable
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2017-12-15' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY ItemId;
```

A side note, but [here is a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) to the MSDN docs describing what are the valid date/time literals for SQL Server.  I prefer to use the ISO format I gave above, but what you used `m/d/y` is also valid.

Comment: Wouldn't that change the overall view count? You'd only count views where the date condition is true, but not all the views of given ItemId, which I think was desired.

Comment: @Demo Interesting point.  But the expected output implies no `WHERE` restriction at all was applied.  My interpretation of the question was that the OP might want to later apply a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: True. This answer might be what the OP asked afterall. Depends whether the date is only used to identify the ItemId and then count all of the views for given ItemId date regardless or just to count views within the specified date range.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a subquery, so that the overall view count is not changed by the WHERE clause restriction. Something such as following:

```
SELECT
    ItemId,
    sum(Views) as viewCount
FROM table t1
WHERE exists (Select itemid From table t2 Where t2.itemid = t1.itemid and [Date] BETWEEN '2017-12-15' AND GETDATE())
GROUP BY ItemId;
```